# Can we keep Sketchy?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

In light of [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/) I'd like to make a featured request.

Please allow RPG.SE to keep the sketchy theme.

When I first came to this site I didn't notice the sketchy theme, I thought it was part of the ambiance here. RPGs have always featured graph paper as part of their culture, it works here.

So please don't take sketchy away, we love it and we will cry. Huge nerdy tears.

I have cried my nerdy tears. Now we must battle for a more appropriate real site design (TM).

Comment: +1 for coloured pencil and graph paper. It's almost as good as a real theme.

Comment: Better yet get us a real one.

Comment: @mxy no doubt that would be preferable..but in the mean time....

Comment: I think this is like the 15th site to say "the sketchy theme seems like it was made just for us" at some point. Jin should just make it the official theme for all sites and take the rest of the year off

Comment: TBH I always thought Sketchy was a custom theme just for us.

Answer (score 13):

STATUS DECLINED! AND NOW YOU KNOW WHY!!!! CONGRATS!

Comment: Long live sketchy!

Comment: I can't upvote this enough!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

No.

But just think...

If/when you graduate, you'll already know what to ask for as your own custom theme...

Comment: that's cold bro :P

Comment: @Shog9 If/when  ... *If/When*! ;-)