# Petition to Keep Sketchy!

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we keep Sketchy?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/can-we-keep-sketchy)

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/

According to that blog post, a new theme will be rolling out to beta sites shortly.  While I think the theme looks great, I'm rather fond of the one we have now, Sketchy.  Based on a very brief survey in chat, I'm not the only one.

The grid gives the look of old school gaming and seems to fit us well.

Is there an option for the site to retain this look?  What do other people think?